# Signed a cheap lease, Texas apartment complex wants me to resign a more expensive one

Tags: united-states, rental-property, texas, lease

I have been in an apartment complex for over a year now. I got a new lease offer $100 less than it is currently for next year both verbally and I just signed the lease at this new rate. That was the rate I began renting at by the way. I have been told this new price multiple times and I even called to check that the paperwork was still being sent. There was some delays which was fine, I just wanted to be sure I didn't have to move in July but I had been considering it given the quality of the unit (lots of repairs and pest control issues). I honestly heard the new price and thought they were taking care of me as a tenant for being a good renter (paying on time, no problems, etc).

Then they called the other day and said that was a mistake and that I need to resign a more expensive lease. I find this unreasonable and asked if they were rescinding this offer. She said yes and asked who I talked to. I don't recall, it was several women in the office. I spoke and corresponded several times with the office. And I do have a new signed lease now. I would have spent this time looking for something else at the same rate or a little more expensive for better quality but I feel bamboozled by a lower rate, that is the sticker price for these apartments anyway.

It is not my fault that they "accidentally" sent the wrong price no more than it would be theirs if I broke my lease early.

What can I do? I want to keep the lower rate.

Comment: You need to review your state's landlord-tenant laws, possibly engage an attorney. This is more of a legal issue vs. personal finance. I'm unfamiliar with TX, but in some states, if you (landlord) execute a lease that had mistakes and want to change it after-the-fact in a way that harms the tenant, you're out of luck.

Comment: If you already signed the lease with them then you need to follow the lease. Can they break it unilaterally? What's the required notice? You may want to check with the local tenant assistance groups.

Comment: Also to add, if your lease "allows" your landlord to do certain things that contradict with tenant laws, that may be an unenforceable clause (again, jurisdiction-dependent. Where I am, there are certain tenant rights that a contract can't force you to relinquish.)

Comment: There are tenant-rights organizations in most cities. I'd suggest contacting the one nearest you to find out what your options are. Note that making a landlord unhappy on the first day you move may have its own costs in delayed repair and so on, so this may or may not be worth fighting even if you're in the right, depending on how civic-minded you are.

Comment: You signed… but did you get the contract signed by them, and do you have that in hand? Or are you still waiting for them to sign it and/or send it to you?

Comment: You can ask this question at [Law.SE] if you put it in hypothetical terms ("suppose someone signs a lease...").